# Read-only parameters - Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

I have a teamcity configuration template. The template has say one parameter called SolutionLocation.

This parameter is used in several places (e.g. used as the value for Path To Solution File in a build step) within the template using the %SolutionLocation% notation. All of that works fine.

I would like to make those things readonly i.e. I only want the creator of each project to define the SolutionLocation parameter value and the rest are provided for him. So I dont want the value of Path To Solution File to be editable. Only the PathToSolution **parameter**

Any way of doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible to prohibit overriding for parameter in TeamCity. Here is the related request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-30867, please vote for it.

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed the link.

Comment: Fixed in TeamCity 10!